# Istio Gateway MUTUAL TLS mode Not Working

Tags: ssl, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have created a GKE Cluster `1.18.17-gke.1901` and I have installed `Istio 1.9.5` on it. My Ingress Gateway Service is of `type: LoadBalancer`.

I am trying to implement `MUTUAL TLS` mode in my `istio-ingressgateway`. The Gateway configuration looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mutual-domain
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - mutual.domain.com
    port:
      name: mutual-domain-https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: mutual-secret
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_2
      mode: MUTUAL
```

I have also setup a corresponding VirtualService and DestinationRule too.

Now, whenever I try to connect to `https://mutual.domain.com` I get the following error:

```
*   Trying 100.50.76.97...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mutual.domain.com (100.50.76.97) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to mutual.domain.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to mutual.domain.com:443
```

If I change the `tls: mode:` to `SIMPLE` I am able to reach the service via the domain name but when it's `MUTUAL` the error above shows up.

The `mutual-secret` is a tls type Kubernets secret and it contains the `tls.crt` and `tls.key`.

```
$ kubectl describe mutual-secret
Name:         mutual-secret
Namespace:    istio-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
tls.crt:  4585 bytes
tls.key:  1674 bytes
```

Is there something missing? Why can't I access my service in `MUTUAL` mode but the same secret works for `SIMPLE` mode?

Comment: If possible, please include the output of `kubectl describe secret mutual-secret`

Comment: @PawełGrondal I have edited my question and add the output of ```kubectl describe secret mutual-secret```.

Comment: I assume you were following [this](https://istio.io/v1.9/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-mutual-tls-ingress-gateway). Seems you are missing `ca.crt` in your secret. Create a new secret with `tls.crt`, `tsl.key` and `ca.crt`, and try again.

Comment: @PawełGrondal yes, I was missing the ```car.crt``` but after providing it, I'm stuck with another error whenever I try to access the URL in browser ```ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming you are following [this](https://istio.io/v1.9/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-mutual-tls-ingress-gateway).*

It seems you are missing `ca.crt` in your secret. Create a new secret with `tls.crt`, `tsl.key` and `ca.crt`, and try again.

---

The `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT` error mentioned in the comments is Chrome/Chromium specific. It means the browser does not recognise Certificate Authority.

Add your CA certificate (`.pem file`) to Chrome/Chromium, you can follow [this](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome). Hopefully it will solve your problem.